# PHP Code To Wish Belated Happy Brthday On Next Date

Tags: php

I am trying to create code which wishes user 3 times...one day before, on birthday and on next day with message "Belated Happy Birthday".

I have a column in mysql data containing birthdate in `YYYY-mm-dd` format.

Now code works for One Day Before and On birthday...BUT NOT on Next Day i.e. For Happy Belated Birthdy.

Code Is as follows -

```
$datetoday = date("m-d");
$happybirthdate = date("m-d", strtotime($userdata["birthdate"]));
$datetoday1 = date("m-d", strtotime(' +1 day'));
$datetoday2 = date('m-d', (strtotime('-1 day', strtotime($datetoday))));

if ($datetoday == $happybirthdate) {
    echo "Site Wishes Happy Birthday To You !!";
}
if ($datetoday1 == $happybirthdate) {
    echo "Site Wishes Happy Birthday To You In Advance !!";
}
if ($datetoday2 == $happybirthdate) {
    echo "Site Wishes Belated Happy Birthday To You !!";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply fetch yesterday's date doing this:

```
$datetoday2 = date("m-d",strtotime(' -1 day'));
```

Comment: Mark the question as correct if it has really solved your problem to help the community.

Answer (score 1):

Please change the line to calculate $datetoday2 as given below:

```
$datetoday2= date('m-d',(strtotime ( '-1 day'  ) ));
```

then it will work as you expected!